# MySQL Error "The server quit without updating PID file"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, linux

All. I am an absolute beginner of ruby on rails and web development.

Due to a lack of my knowledge about web development, I have been struggling one error for weeks, which is `. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file /usr/local/var/mysql/xxxxxxx.local.pid).`

I just have no idea what to do anymore. Here is a list of my attempts to solve the error.

(1) `ps aux | grep mysql`

```
2667   0.0  0.0  2423376    204 s001  R+   10:04PM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn mysql`

sudo kill -9 2667
kill: 2667: No such process
```

(2) `ls -la /usr/local/var/mysql` to check who has an ownership of `/usr/local/var/mysql`

However, the error message

`ls: /usr/local/var/mysql: No such file or directory`

comes out.

I have read many articles that might help me solve the error in both my mother language and english. However, I have not gotten any single clue. Somebody PLEASE HELP ME!!

English is not my first language, so if this post need more information or does not make sense to you, please let me know. Any advice would be appreciated! Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps on the following [link](https://coderwall.com/p/os6woq/uninstall-all-those-broken-versions-of-mysql-and-re-install-it-with-brew-on-mac-mavericks). This will reinstall MySQL on your machine and have you running up in no time from scratch.